# Uploading an image to server from android using HTTP POST request

Tags: php, android, post

I want to upload an image from my android app to a server. I don't know where the problem is exactly in the code i'm using -it's suppose to work ! -. It's the first time I ever do this so I have little knowledge about it.

The code doesn't catch any exceptions, yet it never enters the if statement where the server response is "200".. and the image is never uploaded.

and could you please answer the following ?

1) what does this property mean ?

```
conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", "Thumbnail"+user_id);
```

2) why is the meaning of this line ? I understand it'll use the data output stream to write onto the server , but what are the parameters inside ?

```
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=uploaded_file;filename=Thumbnail"+
                                  user_id+ lineEnd);
```

===========

```
public void upload_to_server(File [] sdDirList, int fileIndex) throws IOException
    {
        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(SettingsActivity.this, "", "Uploading Image...", true);
        final String upLoadServerUri = "server side php script goes here";


        //***File path ***//
        final String uploadFilePath = sdDirList[fileIndex].getCanonicalPath();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, uploadFilePath, 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
        });


       //***Display the dialog of the upload state***//

        new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {
            //Sending thread
                public void run() 
              {
                    dialog.show();

                    String fileName = uploadFilePath;
                    int serverResponseCode = 0;
                    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                    DataOutputStream dos = null;  
                    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
                    String twoHyphens = "--";
                    String boundary = "*****";
                    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
                    byte[] buffer;
                    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
                    File sourceFile = new File(uploadFilePath); 

                    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) 
                    {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "File is not valid..", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
                        });

                         dialog.dismiss(); 
                         return;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Entered else block", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
                        });

                         try 
                         { 

                               // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                             FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                             URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                             // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                             conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                             conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                             conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                             conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                             conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                             conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                             conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                             conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                             conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", "Thumbnail"+user_id); 

                             dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                             dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                             dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=uploaded_file;filename=Thumbnail"+
                                  user_id+ lineEnd);

                             dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                             // create a buffer of  maximum size
                             bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                             bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                             buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                             // read file and write it into form...
                             bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                             while (bytesRead > 0) 
                             {

                               dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                              }

                          // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                             dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                             dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                             // Responses from the server (code and message)
                             serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                             String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                             Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                                     + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                 public void run() {
                                     Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "reached reponses's if", 
                                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          }
                             });
                             if(serverResponseCode == 200)
                             {

                                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                      public void run() 
                                      {


                                          Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                      }
                                  });                
                             }    

                             //close the streams //
                             fileInputStream.close();
                             dos.flush();
                             dos.close();

                             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                 public void run() {
                                     Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "End of Try", 
                                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          }
                             });

                        } 
                         catch (MalformedURLException ex) 
                        {
                             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                 public void run() {
                                     Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "in first catch", 
                                                                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                 }
                             });


                            dialog.dismiss();  
                            ex.printStackTrace();

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", 
                                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });

                            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  

                        } 
                         catch (Exception e) 
                         {
                             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                 public void run() {
                                     Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "in second catch", 
                                                                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                 }
                             });

                            dialog.dismiss();  
                            e.printStackTrace();

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Something went wrong..", 
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                                                             + e.getMessage(), e);  
                        }

                         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                             public void run() {
                                 Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "end of else", 
                                                                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             }
                         });
                        dialog.dismiss();       

                     } // End else block 




              }
        }).start();  

    }
```

============================

PHP SCRIPT :

```
<?php
  
    $file_path = "uploads/";
     
    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

```
conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", "Thumbnail"+user_id);
```

there are two parameter,

first parameter : its a variable name(must be same as defined in php file) defined in your php file for getting file..

second parameter : its a file you want to upload..

2)

```
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=uploaded_file;filename=Thumbnail"+ user_id+ lineEnd);
```

its like query string you are passing to `DataOutputStream`.. here you are passing file throug variable (which you defined upside) and file name for that file..

here,
`uploaded_file` is a variable name defined in server(php) and

`name` & `filename` are field name (don't change it)..you can change its value as your need

if you want nice tutorial  for uploading file visit this link : 
[Multipart HTTP Requests](http://www.androidsnippets.com/multipart-http-requests)

Thank you...

Comment: I wanted to ask more about writeBytes ; are the parameter values related to the "setRequestProperty" ? and does the "filename= .." must match the file I want to upload or is it like a rename ? Sorry but I'm little bit confused ; since the source file was already passed as an input stream..Thank you very much for the link & your answer : ).

Comment: you shouldnot change "filename=" attribute.. it will cause an error in uploading..it is same for all files...

Comment: glad that helped... +1 for it.. :)

Comment: It works probably now, I left the filename as it is without change  & added a missing "777" permission to the uploads folder at the server. Thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This code and this library add httpmime-4.1-beta1.jar :  


  String url = "Your Url";


                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                client.getParams().setParameter(
                        CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
                HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(url);


                MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();



                try {

                        File file1 = new File("Your image Path");
                        FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(file1, "images/jpeg");

                        entity.addPart("uploaded_file", bin1);

                    postMethod.setEntity(entity);
                    HttpResponse response;
                    response = client.execute(postMethod);

                    String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                }

                catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, I'll use this library in case the original code didn't work, it looks more encapsulated & readable.

Answer (score 0):

File Upload Code:

```
String upLoadServerUri_here = "Your url " ;



 private int serverResponseCode = 0;
     private Context mContext ;

public int upload_to_server(final String imagepath) {

        String fileName = imagepath;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null; 
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024 ;
        File sourceFile = new File(imagepath);

        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
          Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + imagepath);

            ((Activity) mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {

                     Toast.makeText(mContext, "Source File not found "+imagepath ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     
              }
             });

             return 0;

        }
        else
        {
             try {


                 FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                 URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri_here);


                 // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                 conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                 conn.setDoInput(true);
                 conn.setDoOutput(true); 
                 conn.setUseCaches(false);
                 conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                 conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "attachment");
                 conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                 conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                 conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

                 dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                           + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                //create a buffer of  maximum size
                 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                 buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                 // read file and write it into form...
                 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize); 
                  while (bytesRead > 0) {

                   dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                  }


                 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
                 serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                 String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                 Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
                 Toast.makeText(mContext, "Got.."+serverResponseMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 


                 if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                 //chk it @ C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Uploads\Work
             ((Activity) mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                          public void run() {


                              Toast.makeText(mContext, "sucesss..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          }
                      });               
                 }   

                 //close the streams //
                 fileInputStream.close();
                 dos.flush();
                 dos.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

              //  dialog.dismiss(); 
                ex.printStackTrace();

                ((Activity) mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex); 
            } catch (Exception e) {


                e.printStackTrace();

                ((Activity) mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Got Exception : see logcat "+serverResponseCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


                Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "  + e.getMessage(), e); 
            }

            return serverResponseCode;

         } 
       }
```

Where *imagepath = "yourselectedimage with full path";*

Comment: void java.net.URLConnection.setRequestProperty(String field, String newValue)



public void setRequestProperty (String field, String newValue) 

Sets the value of the specified request header field. The value will only be used by the current URLConnection instance. This method can only be called before the connection is established.

Parameters
field  the request header field to be set. 
newValue  the new value of the specified property. 

Throws
IllegalStateException  if the connection has been already established. 
NullPointerException  if the parameter field is null.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I understand the request property now, thanks to you & prag's answer, but the code you posted is almost identical, I revised it & there is only one  difference in "writeByte(content...), could you please point me to the mistakes i did in my code ?

Comment: Thanks.. Your file will  not return "Success" till its get the file in proper foramt which is in php if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)), So check in writeByte(content...) and for more details chk http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/03/29/uploading-audio-video-or-image-files-from-android-to-server/